# disabled feature in iPad app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, app-store

i want to release an iPad application to app store. in my application on dashboard there are six buttons and on tap they open six different screens. but among them  one is disabled. User is unable to do anything with it. We just kept it in the app as we are going to implement that feature in the next version. is that fine? is there any chances that my app will get reject by app store guys because of this.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: well on click of that button show alert message with "Coming soon",This your app will not get rejected for this reason.

Comment: @Jignesh, I don't agree with you, it may be rejected based on _AppStore Review Guideline 2.9_.

Comment: @Jignesh sorry but I agree with `holex` only for the reason being developers could develop a feature that would never make it passed the apple review process so they say it's disabled and then they flip a switch on the server side to enabled that feature and there you have it something that isn't allowed in the app store. So I can see this getting rejected based on that reason

Answer (score 1):

As per my experience Apple will **Reject** your application saying that either you have to implement that functionality or you have to remove that disabled button.

Answer (score 1):

it may be rejected based on *AppStore Review Guideline*:

> **2.9** Apps that are "demo", "trial", or "test" versions will be rejected. Beta Apps may only be submitted through TestFlight and must follow the TestFlight guidelines

it would be more reasonable to implement the functionality; or not showing such features which are not part of the application at all – none of those cases cause rejection.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add like a simple alertView saying « This feature will be available in the next version, stay tuned ! » or something ? Would be a way better UX overall. Either that, or hide the button for now. Either way, don't let a button do nothing with no user feedback, this sounds terrible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think app store will reject your iPad application. You should use rather **web view** control(in Android) in which you can show any web page or something like that, if you want to provide the facility that after installation of your app, uses can get the updated details from it. Just give it a thought.

Comment: Makes sense. Show a coming soon page  till dev is completed, and then once new update is out you can change the page and show a message to user to update the app.

Comment: u got it exactly,,, :)

Comment: ...and that will cause a direct rejection, guys.